# Loading WPF satellite resources dynamically

Tags: wpf, localization, directory-structure, satellite-assembly

I've read about satellite-assemblies being used in WPF localizations. However, I would like to ask if there is a way to load the satellite-assemblies without following the pre-defined directory structure that depends on the language (ex. If the system language is English, the WPF application looks for the satellite-assembly inside the "en-US" subfolder).

This is because I would like to simply swap the satellite-assemblies when distributing the software package without having to create a specific folder per language that would hold the assemblies. I would just like to have the satellite-assembly and the main executable in the same directory.

Is this possible and is there even an easy way to do this like simply loading the resource file on application startup once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you are stuck with using the directories.